# How to find files containing two search terms in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

In the Visual Studio I am trying to find files which contain both "readonly" and "token". Is there a way to do that? Is there anything like "readonly + token"

something like

[image]

Comment: If you want to find a *line* with those two words, check "Use Regular Expressions" below and type `^(?=.*\breadonly\b)(?=.*\btoken\b).*$`

Answer (score 0):

```
((token)(.*\n)*.*(readonly))|((readonly)(.*\n)*.*(token))
```

Don't forget to check "Regular Expressions".